# Next.js API fetch data every 5 minutes

Tags: node.js, database, next.js, setinterval, prisma

So I have a next.js application, and a prisma database, I'm trying to fetch a list of users ids with the steam API and then save it to the database, and I want to run it for every 5 minutes, is it possible to do that or do I need to make a new file and then run it with `next start`?

Comment: are you looking for cron jobs? Have a look [here](https://codesaying.com/cron-job-in-nodejs/) , maybe it helps

Comment: @DhruvPal In which file do i put it at in my next.js app? Or do i need to make a separate file and run it separately

Comment: Because API routes run as serverless functions you can't really schedule calls from within them. You can however setup a cron job externally that would call the API route. See https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/solutions/cron-jobs for an approach using GH actions.